# Need to remove elements from an ArrayList of ArrayLists<Double>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have code that processes wav files and sorts collections of double values (audio samples) into an ArrayList and each of these ArrayLists is then sorted into an ArrayList of ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<Double> sampleEvent = new ArrayList<Double>();

ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> EventsCollect = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
```

I have code that attempts to remove ArrayLists that are less than a certain size from the collection.

However all it seems to do is half the list and doesn't remove the correct ArrayLists from the collection.

Please see my code below:

```
for (int loop = 0 ;   loop <  EventsCollect.size(); loop++) {
    if ( EventsCollect.get(loop).size() <  200000) {
         EventsCollect.remove(loop);
    }
}
```

After doing this, ArrayLists remain in the collection that are only triple figures in size.

Any advice about how to correct this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase, that means they start with lowercase. So `EventsCollect` should be `eventsCollect`.

Comment: Can you describe what the code is supposed to do? Which elements should it remove exactly and when?

Comment: Note that when you remove an element from the front, all remaining elements get shifted (change their index). So If you have `(1,2,3,4,5)`, and remove the first and then the second element, you DO NOT end up with `(3,4,5)`, but with `(2,4,5)`.

Comment: You may want to look at `removeRange` or `trimToSize` to remove a lot of elements in one go.

Comment: It's **very** memory-inefficient to store large amounts of Doubles in an ArrayList as that creates an object wrapper for each double, making it take many times its ordinary size. Using `double[]` will get you much further in terms of memory usage.

Comment: you need to do a reverse loop (count down) when trying to delete from a list. the reason is that all later entries are shifted up. this results in an entry being skipped for checking. alternatively, you can try using the streams and filter method (see my ans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you increment the loop counter even if you remove an element. By doing this, you skip an element in the loop. Just change your if statement:

```
    int loop = 0; // loop counter
    while (loop < EventsCollect.size()) {
        if (EventsCollect.get(loop).size() < 200000) {
            EventsCollect.remove(loop);
        }
        else
            loop++;
    }
```

Or you can loop backwards through the ArrayList:

```
for (int i = EventsCollect.size() - 1; i >= 0; i --){
    if (EventsCollect.get(i).size() > 200000)
        EventsCollect.remove(i);
}
```

This works because you will always loop through the array a constant amount of time. If you look at your code, `EventsCollect.size()` changes as you remove elements, thus not looping
through every element. This should be your cue that something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in java 8, you can try removing with predicate using lambda expressions

```
    EventsCollect = EventsCollect.stream() 
               //we want to retain only samples with more than 200_000 count
               .filter(sampleEvent -> sampleEvent.size() >=  200_000) 
               //we collect everything that we want back into our EventsCollect list
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

as a side note, you might want to rename EventsCollect to eventsCollect (small letter e).

anyway, the reason why only half of your entries are evaluate is because when you 
delete an entry, all the bottom gets shifted up by one. the effect of this is that the first item of the newly shifted entry will not be evaluated.

assume we have 4 entries, and i is currently at 1 (pointing to 100k)

```
{230k, 100k, 20k, 122k}
```

the loop evaluates and removes 100k

```
{230, 20k, 122k}
```

now all the values are shifted up by one, and i is incremented to 2 (pointing at 122k). notice that 20k is in the position of 1, and is now skipped. the loop will evaluate and remove 122k instead.

```
{230, 20k}
```

to fix your code with minimum changes, you need to do a reverse iteration (from last entry to the first)

```
for (int loop = EventsCollect.size()-1 ;   loop >=0; loop--) {
    if ( EventsCollect.get(loop).size() <  200000) {
         EventsCollect.remove(loop);
    }
}
```